# What is the effect of performance of a SQL query when have aggregate function and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 2 queries :

**1.**

```
SELECT u.unitId unitId,
         u.unitScode 'unitScode',
         ( Cast(Count(vd.Date) AS FLOAT) / u.timeDiff ) * 100 'BookingCount',
         u.tradeStartTime,
         u.tradeStopTime,
         u.minimumSlot,
         u.maximumTerm
  FROM   @allDates vd
         INNER JOIN CommcmlBookingDetail cd
                 ON vd.Date BETWEEN cd.dtFromTime AND cd.dtToTime
                    AND Datepart(minute, vd.date) = Datepart(minute, cd.dtFromTime)
         INNER JOIN CommCmlBooking cb
                 ON cb.hMy = cd.hBooking
                    AND cb.iStatus = 1
                    AND cb.iType = 525
         INNER JOIN @unitsInfo u
                 ON u.unitId = cb.hUnit
                    AND Cast(vd.Date AS DATE) BETWEEN Cast(@BookingFromDate AS DATE) AND Cast(@BookingToDate AS DATE)
                    AND Cast(vd.Date AS TIME) BETWEEN Cast(u.tradeStartTime AS TIME) AND Cast(u.tradeStopTime AS TIME)
  WHERE  cb.hRecord = case when @amendmentId = 0 then cb.hRecord else @amendmentId end 
  GROUP  BY u.unitId,
            u.unitScode,
            u.minimumSlot,
            u.tradeStartTime,
            u.timeDiff,
            u.tradeStopTime,
            u.maximumTerm;
```

**2.**

```
INSERT INTO @tempBookingCount
      SELECT u.unitId,
             u.timeDiff
      FROM   @allDates vd
             INNER JOIN CommcmlBookingDetail cd
                     ON vd.Date BETWEEN cd.dtFromTime AND cd.dtToTime
                        AND Datepart(minute, vd.date) = Datepart(minute, cd.dtFromTime)
             INNER JOIN CommCmlBooking cb
                     ON cb.hMy = cd.hBooking
                        AND cb.iStatus = 1
                        AND cb.iType = 525
             INNER JOIN @unitsInfo u
                     ON u.unitId = cb.hUnit
                        AND Cast(vd.Date AS DATE) BETWEEN Cast(@BookingFromDate AS DATE) AND Cast(@BookingToDate AS DATE)
                        AND Cast(vd.Date AS TIME) BETWEEN Cast(u.tradeStartTime AS TIME) AND Cast(u.tradeStopTime AS TIME)
      WHERE  cb.hRecord = case when @amendmentId = 0 then cb.hRecord else @amendmentId end 


INSERT INTO @unitBookingCount
  SELECT tt.unitID,
         u.unitScode,
         ( Cast(Count(tt.unitID) AS FLOAT) / tt.timeDiff ) * 100,
         u.tradeStartTime,
         u.tradeStopTime,
         u.minimumSlot,
         u.maximumTerm
  FROM   @tempBookingCount tt
         INNER JOIN @unitsInfo u
                 ON u.unitId = tt.unitID
  GROUP  BY tt.unitID,
            tt.timeDiff,
            u.tradeStartTime,
            u.tradeStopTime,
            u.minimumSlot,
            u.maximumTerm,
            u.unitScode
```

I have separated the first query into 2 parts, and i can a huge difference in  the  performance!
The first query take **14 seconds** when executed for 5 months where as next query take **4 seconds**.

Comment: So MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Your original query uses 2 table variables @allDates and @unitsInfo.

By using table variables, you aren't giving SQL a fighting chance of optimizing the query because there are no statistics on table variables and the row count estimations and query plan are impacted.

One reference, you can find many more:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/08/24/query-performance-and-table-variables.aspx

Try the original with #TempTables instead of @TableVars